# Highlight selected item in a ListView not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a button when I click it show me a fragment with a `listview`.

```
stateFragment = new StateFragment();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.add(R.id.relativLaout_Sates, stateFragment, "StatFag").commit();
```

and this is the code on `onCreateview()` StateFragment

```
 listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.row_layout, R.id.row1, items);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 listView.setSelectionFromTop(getpos, getoffset);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(StateFragment.this);
```

and the code for the layout for the listview:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    />
```

and for the row :

```
 <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSiz_home_page"
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_txt_add_it"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    style="@style/MyTextTheme"/>
```

and the code for bg_txt_add_it is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@color/blue2" android:state_activated="true"/>
```

and in the  onItemClick the code is:

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    view.getFocusables(getpos);
    view.setSelected(true);
```

when I open this `ListView` again, it will be scrolled to the item was selected before but the highlight selection disappear after a tow second, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by **'when I open this ListView again,**'. Are you navigating to a different screen from the fragment containing the listview. What are you asking in that case is to retain the UI state between screen transitions which mostly you have to handle manually. There are cases where the UI component retains the UI, but it depends

Comment: No,same screen , when I click it on button it will create a new stateFragment = new StateFragment();